# Redirect to new page through dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

We’re trying to redirect users through a button to a new page with javascript/jquery. When clicking the button a piece of text also gets copied to clipboard. The user gets an alert confirming this text has been copied. 
We would then like the site to redirect to a new page. Either through clicking the OK button on the alert, or automatically.

Is this possible through the alert? Can we create a automatic delayed redirect when the user clicks the button so they see both the alert message and redirects some second later?

Code here:

```
<div class="country-container">
          <button class="promocode" onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">
          <p style="text-decoration: none;">Use promocode:<br><span id="p1">SPAIN-2018</span></p>
</div>   

    <script>      
    function copyToClipboard(element) {
      var $temp = $("<input>");
      $("body").append($temp);
      $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      $temp.remove();

      alert(“You’ve copied the promo code " + $temp.val());
    }    
    </script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should do what you need.

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();

    alert("You’ve copied the promo code " + $("#p1").text()); 
  }
  
$("button").click(
    function() {
        setTimeout(
            function() {
               //alert("Redirect here");
               window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
            },
            1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="country-container">
  <button type="button" class="promocode" onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">
  <p style="text-decoration: none;">Use promocode:<br>
  <span id="p1">SPAIN-2018</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `confirm`:

```
if (confirm("OK?")) {
  window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
} else {
  window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a deferred Object called `when()`. Use this Object.

**Example:**

```js
function copyToClipboard( element ) {
    var $temp = $( '<input>' );

    $( 'body' ).append( $temp );
    $temp.val( $( element ).text() ).select();
    document.execCommand( 'copy' );
    $temp.remove();
    alert( 'You\'ve copied the promo code ' + $temp.val() );
}

function redirect() {
    $.when( copyToClipboard( '#p1' ) ).done(function( ) {
        $( '.country-container' ).text( 'redirected to: http://stackoverflow.com' );
        /*window.location.replace( 'http://stackoverflow.com' );*/
    } );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="country-container">
    <button class="promocode" onclick="redirect()">Copy to Clipboard</button>
    <p style="text-decoration: none;">Use promocode:<br><span id="p1">SPAIN-2018</span></p>
</div>
```